# Documenting parameters of Scala functions defined via val

Tags: scala, scaladoc

When documenting parameters of methods with Scaladoc, we can write:

```scala
  /** Is number even 
   * @param i number
   * @return true if i is even, false otherwise
   */
  def isEvenDef(i: Int) = i % 2 == 0
```

Which after generating the docs (e.g. via `doc` from sbt) yields nice documentation of the parameters (pointless in this example, but useful in general):

[image]

However, writing an analogous function via `val` and using the same documentation:

```scala
  /** Is number even 
   * @param i number
   * @return true if i is even, false otherwise
   */
  val isEvenVal = (i: Int) => i % 2 == 0
```

The `param` does not seem to show in the generated documentation:

[image]

Is there a way do document the parameters for functions defined via `val` such that they show similarly to the parameters of methods defined via `def`?

Comment: Sadly no AFAIK, because `param` work on **methods** not in **functions**.

Comment: I don't understand why you can't use a def for this, though. To make it a function, all you need is an underscore after it (and sometimes not even that)